# How can I calculate the total capacitance of a pair in this cable by using data-sheet?

Tags: cables, capacitance

Below depicts a 100m 3-pair STP cable, where my focus is the pair 1 on the top:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHO37U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I know the output impedance of the source Rs, and if I want to calculate the LP filter effect of the cable on the V1 signal; how can I calculate the total capacitance C1 for the Pair 1.

How can I calculate the total capacitance of the pair from the data-sheet like [this one](http://pub.tmb.com/ProPlex/CAT6a/pdf/ProPlex-CAT6a-A4-web.pdf)? Which parameters should be taken into account?

(Consider the signal frequency V1 is low like 100Hz(sinusoidal), I guess we can neglect the transmission line effects)

Answer (score 1):

The capacitance is right in the datasheet:

[image]

Comment: We dont use capacitance unbalance? What is that one? Thanks

Comment: Secondly which parameter shows me to calculate total Rcable in my figure? I mean DC resistance per meter

Comment: @newage2000 look at the table and read it.